# updateParams not working in ol3gm

Tags: ol3-google-maps

I have migrated my project from openlayers to ol3-google-maps. Some issues observer are noted below.

1. tiled.getSource().updateParams({"time": Date.now()}) function not working.
2. Zoom functionality is little laggy.

Is there any other method to refresh tile layers?

Answer (score 0):

### How to refresh in ol3-google-maps

There's a [refresh](https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps/blob/master/src/olgm/olgooglemaps.js#L179-L185) method in olgm that goes through the layers "that are watched" (i.e. that are being rendered as GoogleMaps overlays) that refreshes them.  So far, only the "ImageWMS" layers are handled.

Since you're using tiled layers, calling that method wouldn't fix your issue. But, if you're interested, you could contribute this feature to the project through a Pull Request, on GitHub.

### Zoom is a little laggy

Would you please [create an issue](https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps/issues) create an issue about this on olgm's GitHub?  If you could demonstrate the problem, it would be nice (can be a demo, animated gif, etc.)